# Setting up Whitebox Tools for R

Tags: r, installation, whitebox-tools

I ran into issues setting up Whitebox Tools for R. I installed the whitebox package, downloaded the Whitebox Tools and place them in the R folder in Documents. However, using the functions results in an error message. Even running

```
print(wbt_version())
```

throws an error message:

```
Error :  

Error running WhiteboxTools
  whitebox.exe_path: "C:/Users/USERNAME/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/whitebox/WBT/whitebox_tools.exe"; File exists? TRUE
  Arguments: --version=  

Error in system(exeargs, intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = ignore.stderr, : 'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\Users\USERNAME\DOCUME~1\R\WIN-LI~1\4.1\whitebox\WBT\WHITEB~1.EXE --version'
[1] "Error : \nError running WhiteboxTools\n  whitebox.exe_path: \"C:/Users/USERNAME/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/whitebox/WBT/whitebox_tools.exe\"; File exists? TRUE\n  Arguments: --version\n\nError in system(exeargs, intern = TRUE, ignore.stderr = ignore.stderr, : 'CreateProcess' failed to run 'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\DOCUME~1\\R\\WIN-LI~1\\4.1\\whitebox\\WBT\\WHITEB~1.EXE --version'\n\n"
```

It looks like it can locate the whitebox.exe correctly. However, since it's not working correctly, there seems to be something off with the setup, but I can’t tell what. It seems odd that the file path apparently contains both \ and / (`\"C:/Users`). I set the whitebox.exe to always run as administrator. I’m on Windows 11, just in case that is relevant information.
Any ideas what I might be missing (or other information I could/should provide)?

Comment: Can you run that .exe from the Windows command line or PowerShell?

Comment: Further to the above, I've seen Windows systems set up so that executables in user folders can't run, only system exes and stuff installed "properly" in some sense. Random downloaded .exe files? Ooh no, virus warning virus warning alert alert! If you try running it from the Windows CMD (or maybe double-clicking) you might see an informative warning...

Comment: Have you installed whitebox package from CRAN? Or R-Forge? I've got it from CRAN and ran a command `whitebox::install_whitebox()` which took care of all installation processes. The whitebox tool was installed into the R folder (same as your setting). Looks like it is working properly.

Comment: @Spacedman, I tried running it from the command line. Similar to double clicking, the windows message popped up whether I really want to execute it. I did, but  received the same error message in R when I run a whitebox function.  I even added the folder and the .exe to the Windows Defender allowed list and disabled the security warnings. Unfortunately, to no avail...

Comment: @Kazuhito, I got the whitebox package from CRAN. When I run whitebox::install_whitebox(), it just tells me the installation path of the whitebox_tools.exe.

Comment: Rincewind, I guess you have already installed whitebox package before. If I re-run `whitebox::install_whitebox()`, it returns the installation path message, as you have described. How about removing the existing package (`remove.packages("whitebox")`) and re-install it?

Comment: @Kazuhito, was worth a try, unfortunately still the same message. The interesting thing is, both my office and home computer throw that error message (near-identical PC builds), my laptop, however, runs whitebox functions without a hitch. I might try uninstalling and reinstalling both R and Rstudio at this point.

Comment: Alright, the issues might have been caused by a long file path and/or a file path with spaces. I use OneDrive for Business and the OneDrive for Business naming is utterly ridiculous, ending up with crazy long OneDrive folder names, in my case containing multiple spaces and a dash. When I copied the project folder to the desktop, the functions run as expected. I had run into similar issues before and thought I had tested the folder location thing before I posted the question - but apparently, I had not. My bad!